# O(fib n) complexity algorithms?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, fibonacci, sicp

While watching [lecture 1B of the Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlbMuv-jix8&feature=BF&list=PLE18841CABEA24090&index=2), there's a function that calculates Fibonacci numbers. The lecturer points out that the time complexity is O(fib n) - I've never seen that before. I've seen it rounded to constant, linear, n+m, quadratic, polynomial, or exponential complexity, but are there any other O(fib n) algorithms or other interesting big O notations that should be looked at or studied?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it/46607#46607

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`O(fib N)` is nothing strange or special - it is exactly the same thing as exponential complexity - it is just that the lecturer did not take the time to spell it out. (You can easily* bound `fib(N)` with `phi^n`.)

You don't have to believe me though - you would have a better explanation on [Math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com).

*: I'll clarify what I mean by "easily" - it means that the proof is readily available, for example in [that wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) (thanks to the previous answerer that originally gave the link to it).